# how to change output of lambda function in filter + lambda?

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

I am a beginner in python and currently I am learning how lambda functions work. I want to know if there is a way for me to influence the output of a lambda + filter combo, because if I have understood how they work correctly, you can only return the element of the list you are iterating over, i.e., the argument of the lambda function. What I am exactly trying to achieve can be shown using a list comprehension

```
numbers = [25, 91, 22, -7, -20]
numbers_div_5_str = [str(n) for n in numbers if n % 5 == 0]
```

This gives a list of numbers in the form of a string that are divisible by 5.
I want to achieve the same using lambda + filter, if possible

This is what I tried doing

```
numbers = [25, 91, 22, -7, -20]
numbers_div_5 = list(filter(lambda a : a % 5 == 0, numbers))
```

output -> `[25, -20]`
Expected output -> `['25', '-20']`

Comment: You need an additional call like `map(str,...)` in-between.

Comment: Note that you won't change the output of the lambda itself (it must return booleans in any way).

Comment: @Swifty it must return booleans? we can have any other expression too right, just that you can't have a boolean and follow that up with an expression

Comment: The function used as a filter key is supposed to be a boolean function (in any case, the boolean values of its returns will be considered). So if you want your outputs to be strings, you must work on the returns of the filter, not on the lambda itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example with a list comprehension you are doing two kinds of operations. 1) filtering elements from the original list with `if n % 5 == 0` and 2) casting the values to be of type `str` with `str(n)`.

Using the `filter` function can help you achieve your filtering (1) in exactly the way you tried already. The only thing remaining is to cast the values to `str`. Unfortunately you cannot just say `str([1,2,3])` to transform all numbers in that list to be of type `str`. This has to be done element-wise. To achieve this you can use `map`. The syntax is roughly the same as `filter`, but this will take each element from your list and apply some kind of logic to it. This logic can be specified in a `lambda` function, or in this case you can simply use `str` on its own to cast your values.

here is an example in code

```
numbers = [25, 91, 22, -7, -20]
filtered_numbers = filter(lambda a : a % 5 == 0, numbers)
filtered_str_numbers = list(map(str, filtered_numbers))
```

Or more concise:

```
filtered_str_numbers = list(map(str, filter(lambda a : a % 5 == 0, numbers)))
```

Of course it's good to explore these functions and how they work for your knowledge, but in my experience it's totally fine to stick to list comprehensions in most cases.